# Not able to render a single frame from this scene in eevee, how can I optimize this project for rendering performance without losing quality?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, optimization

In this EEVEE scene I used [Jsplacement](https://windmillart.net/?p=jsplacement#:%7E:text=JSplacement%20is%20a%20cross%2Dplatform,JavaScript%20and%20built%20on%20Electron) to produce a robotic atmosphere. As much as I love the look of it I believe it's eating up all my CPU power and memory. My current PC specs: AMD Ryzen 7 3700X, 16gb of ram and an RTX 3070. I also tried rendering on a PC with 32gb of ram and it maxed out. I tried an add on Normal Groups Master which helped the fps of the rendered viewport but did nothing for actual rendering. I tried to bake my indirect lighting and it crashed. I played around with my render settings while trying not to sacrifice too much quality and couldn't find anything that would render a single frame. There must be something I can do to at least get it to slowly render the scene I just can't figure it out. with the addon i was able to watch the scene in my render viewport so it can't be that heavy? I have bigger plans for this scene and environment, so it would be nice to get it fully optimized.

[Download .blend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KIl36xaoyf2ee5NgpYBmJdMfHCvfjFmc/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Never heard of 'Jsplacement'. I assume that's a third-party addon in which case you'll have to ask the addon author directly.

Comment: @JohnEason its not an add on its a separate free program that generates displacement and color maps in the form of images that i can then add to my image and displacement textures. Im not sure they would actually get back to me but i can see. you can check them out here if you want: https://windmillart.net/?p=jsplacement#:~:text=JSplacement%20is%20a%20cross%2Dplatform,JavaScript%20and%20built%20on%20Electron.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: screenshot]

Your objects have *Subdivision Surface* modifiers with a viewport level 4 and **level 6(!) for render**. Because of that, the scene has already over 9 million vertices when you open the blend file.

Keep in mind that each level of the *Subdivision Surface* modifier roughly doubles, triples, or even quadruples the number of vertices depending on the geometry. The number is increasing exponentially.

That means at render time you have something like 153 million vertices that require 32 GB RAM.

Here is the result of the stress test. (Don't try this at home ;-)

To recap: Level 4 = 9 million vertices, level 6 = 153 million vertices.

[image: up to the limit]

To render the image lower the subdivision levels for the render to 3 or 4, especially when the object is in the background or not visible to the camera there is no need to go crazy with the subdivisions.

Alternatively, you can bake normal maps to fake the displacement.